# Fill DataGridView on condition from database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have MySQL database and a DataGridView in C# and to fill the DataGridView I do the following:

```
        schoolDataSet schl = new schoolDataSet();
        schoolDataSetTableAdapters.studentinfoTableAdapter adptr = new schoolDataSetTableAdapters.studentinfoTableAdapter();
        adptr.Fill(schl.studentinfo);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = schl.studentinfo.DefaultView;
```

and undesired columns I make them `visible = false` from DataGridView properties but I came with a problem if I want to specify what data (rows) to fill in DataGridView such applying a where condition like:
`fill data in DataGridView WHERE IsActive = 1` so can I still use the above code with some modifications or I have to write SQL query and fill the DataGridView manually ?

Comment: You can create a DATAVIEW from your dataset and bind it to your GridView

Comment: Please any another hint I'm trying and searching but nothing worked well...any reference or link ?

Comment: see if this link helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy5b8exc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

After searching and trying tons of codes I got it as following in simplest code:
In the code above just comment out last line which is `dataGridView1.DataSource = schl.studentinfo.DefaultView;` or simply replace it with the following

```
DataView dv = new DataView(schoolDataSet.studentinfo, "IsActive = 'false'", "id", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Which creates a new `DataView` and filters according to `IsActive` column with `false value`, the third parameter `id` is to sort based-on, and finally you can write another line
`dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;` that will tell the DataGridView to load data from DataView.

Hope to save someone's time.
Big thanks goes to `@Karthik Ganesan`